# Handlebars bind-attr

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Could you please help me with why this won't work. I want to add a class "plus-article" if IsPlusArticle is true. The first, this.ArticleId, works fine.

```
<script id="articles-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each articles}}
    <article role="article" id="article-{{this.ArticleId}}" {{bind-attr class="this.IsPlusArticle:plus-article"}}>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a [emberjs](/questions/tagged/emberjs) tag so I assume that this is an [handlebars](/questions/tagged/handlebars) project.

`bind-attr` is an [Ember](http://emberjs.com/) specific helper that binds attributes to values in your model. However, if you just want to add `plus-article` to your classes if `IsPlusArticle` without data-binding, you can just use the `#if` helper

```
  <article role="article" id="article-{{this.ArticleId}}" {{#if isPlusArticle}}class="plus-article"{{/if}}>
  </article>
```